# How to add windows on Ubuntu bootmanager?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

Im using both windows and Ubuntu on my laptop pc.  I mostly use windows but whenever I want to switch to Ubuntu i have to go to bios and choose the partition where Ubuntu is installed and then choose Ubuntu from the list of options.  Is there any other way to have both options (windows and linux)  and choose from there the os i want to use without having to go through that trouble?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu,
Try run `sudo update-grub` in terminal.
On next boot, you can find installed OS.

You can also try software called 'grub-customzer'.
More details about Grub Customizer is here : https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Comment: I downloaded grub Customizer.  What do i do next?